# Help with Proof of the Chain Rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove the chain rule. I started out using the standard Frechet Derivative definition. After getting stuck (and generally disliking the heavy use of inequalities), I adopted an approach a friend showed me using error terms.

A function $\varepsilon : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is an error term iff $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{|\varepsilon(h)|}{|h|} = 0$.

A map $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ iff there exists a linear map $f'|_x : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and an error term $\varepsilon : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f(x+h) - f(x) = f'|_xh + \varepsilon(h)$

This should be equivalent to the standard definition, because given a Frechet derivative, we can simply take $\varepsilon(h) = f(x+h) - f(x) - f'|_xh$. Conversely, we can subtract the $f'|_xh$ term from both sides, divide by a nonzero $|h|$, take the limit, and let the right hand side vanish.

Now suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^s$ are differentiable. This gives us two equations to work with.

$$f(x+h) - f(x) = f'|_xh + \varepsilon(h) \\
g(f(x) + h) - gf(x) = g'|_{f(x)}h + \eta(h)$$

We substitute $f(x+h)-f(x)$ for $h$ in the second equation.

$$\begin{align*}
gf(x + h) - gf(x) = g'|_{f(x)}(f(x + h) - f(x)) + \eta(f(x + h) - f(x)) \\
= g'|_{f(x)}f'|_xh + g'|_{f(x)}\varepsilon(e) + \eta(f'|_xh + \varepsilon(h))
\end{align*}$$

If you squint at the end of that last line, you can see I have the equation in the necessary form. All that is left is to show $g'|_{f(x)}\varepsilon(e) + \eta(f'|_xh + \varepsilon(h))$ is an error term.

I think I can easily show that the sum of two error terms is again an error term. However, I'm having trouble with showing $\eta(f'|_xh + \varepsilon(h))$ is an error term.

I feel like there should be a simple way to build error terms from others (via addition and via composition). However, I can't seem to make progress with that idea. (And it seems weird that I'm working with a function that is "linear plus an-error-term").

Any thoughts on how I might attack this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark that $\frac{\eta(f'_x h + \epsilon(h)}{|h|} = \frac{\eta(f'_x h + \epsilon(h))}{|f'_x h + \epsilon(h)|} \times \frac{|f'_x h + \epsilon(h)|}{|h|}$. The second term is bounded when $h \rightarrow 0$ since $f'_x$ is linear and since $\frac{\epsilon(h)}{|h|}$ tends to $0$ when $h$ tends to $0$. The first term is $\frac{\eta(h')}{|h'|}$, with $h' = f'_x h + \epsilon(h)$. When $h$ tends to $0$, $h'$ also tends to $0$. Hence the first term tends to $0$ when $h$ tends to $0$. This proves that the whole term is an error term in your terminology.

In general, one uses the notation $o(h)$ for an error term and one can develop a lot of operations on these notations. Have you ever heard of that ?

Comment: Ahh. I had a feeling I was missing a "division" somewhere! I had seen the little-oh notation, but I don't like how it's used. My formal training is in computer science, and you might say I came over to math because I couldn't stomach saying $f(x) = o(x)$ :)

Comment: After verifying this, I think I'm a little hesitant on one last bit. I can see how the second term tends to $k$ (the bounding coefficient of $f'_x$). But I'm not satisfied with the argument to show $|\frac{k \eta(f'|_xh + \varepsilon(h))}{|f'|_xh + \varepsilon(h)|}$ goes to 0. (In the framework I'm using, limits are binding forms. But $h'$ isn't a free variable, since it has been given a definition, and thus, you can't take the limit over it). I'm trying to prove it with a direct $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, but I'm having trouble.

Comment: Consider the two functions $f_1: h \mapsto f'_x h + \epsilon(h)$ and $f_2: h' \mapsto \frac{\eta(h')}{|h'|}$. You know that both $f_1$ and $f_2$ have limits $0$ at $0$. By composition of limits, this shows that $f_2 \circ f_1$ also has limit $0$ at $0$, which is what you want. Remark that the property of composition of limits is really a basic one, which you can prove by $\epsilon,\delta$ arguments.

Comment: Ah awesome. I ended up proving it last night the hard way, but thanks for showing me the underlying reason.